# data.table fails when it is an inherited class

Tags: r, oop, data.table

I'm having some difficulty using the inheritance structure with `data.table`. When I apply a new sub-class to a data.table object, the object fails to revert to the `data.table` class when called on to do `data.table` operations. Here is an example:

```
library('data.table')

dat <- data.table(x = 1:10, y = LETTERS[1:10])
dat <- structure(dat, class = c('new_class', 'data.table'))

dat[, .(x)]
dat[, z:= 5 * x]
```

Each of the two `data.table` operations above return the following error messages:

```
Error in setnames(x, value) : x is not a data.table or data.frame
Error in setnames(x, value) : x is not a data.table or data.frame
In addition: Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(dat, , `:=`(z, 5 * x)) :
  Invalid .internal.selfref detected and fixed by taking a (shallow) copy of the data.table so that := can add this new column by reference. At an earlier point, this data.table has been copied by R (or was created manually using structure() or similar). Avoid names<- and attr<- which in R currently (and oddly) may copy the whole data.table. Use set* syntax instead to avoid copying: ?set, ?setnames and ?setattr. If this message doesn't help, please report your use case to the data.table issue tracker so the root cause can be fixed or this message improved.
```

It seems that it not referring to the `data.table` class to execute the `.` and `:=` methods. Why is this?

Comment: Set the class with `class(dat) <- c("new_class", class(dat))`.

Comment: Or use `dat <- structure(dat, class = c('new_class', 'data.table', "data.frame"))`. A data.table is *always*  also a data.frame.

Comment: To avoid copying of the data.table object when setting attributes, do `data.table::setattr(dat, "class", c("new_class", class(dat)))`.

Comment: Thanks. I still get a warning msg w/ the first fix from Roland; the solution from @JdeMello appears to work the best